# How to make this search filter with accordion show results by the content inside too?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you can solve this, you are a genius.

**With only JavaScript.**

So, as of right now, I'm only able to search the accordion by its title. By I also want to be able to look for its content inside.

And give the result or tab that contains that search or content.

Not a duplicate, since it's just JavaScript, with no jQuery.

Any help would be useful.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accor");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#myInput {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 23px 11px 13px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.accor {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.active,
.accor:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.accor:after {
  content: 'open';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "close";
}

.panel {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.1s ease-out;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.otras {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search...">
<ul id="myUL">



  <li> <a class="accor">1House</a>

    <div class="panel">
      <div class="otras">
        <p class=title>2Search by this too</p>
        <p>3This is a sentence</p>
      </div>



      <div class="otras">
        <p class=title>4Also this</p>
        <p>5Another sentence to search </p>
      </div>


      <div class="otras">
        <p class=title>6And this too</p>
        <p>7Example of sentence</p>
      </div>


    </div>
  </li>


  <li> <a class="accor">8Search here</a>

    <div class="panel">
      <div class="otras">
        <p class=title> 9A different set of title </p>
        <p>10A different set of </p>
      </div>



      <div class="otras">
        <p class=title>11Also this</p>
        <p>12Another sentence to search </p>
      </div>


      <div class="otras">
        <p class=title>13And this too</p>
        <p>14Example of sentence</p>
      </div>


    </div>
  </li>



</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your JS a little bit to get it to work. The problem with your code is here:

`txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;`

You are searching an "OR" value that doesn't exist. If you look at your definition of the `a` variable, you'll see that it's referencing the anchor tag in the `li`.

You need to combine the anchor tag `AND` the content of the tabs.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue, otras;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    otras = li[i].getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    txtValue = a.innerText + otras.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accor");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#myInput {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 23px 11px 13px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.accor {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.active,
.accor:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.accor:after {
  content: 'open';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "close";
}

.panel {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.1s ease-out;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.otras {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search...">
<ul id="myUL">



  <li> <a class="accor">1House</a>

    <div class="panel">
      <div class="otras">
        <p class=title>2Search by this too</p>
        <p>3This is a sentence</p>
      </div>



      <div class="otras">
        <p class=title>4Also this</p>
        <p>5Another sentence to search </p>
      </div>


      <div class="otras">
        <p class=title>6And this too</p>
        <p>7Example of sentence</p>
      </div>


    </div>
  </li>


  <li> <a class="accor">8Search here</a>

    <div class="panel">
      <div class="otras">
        <p class=title> 9A different set of title </p>
        <p>10A different set of </p>
      </div>



      <div class="otras">
        <p class=title>11Also this</p>
        <p>12Another sentence to search </p>
      </div>


      <div class="otras">
        <p class=title>13And this too</p>
        <p>14Example of sentence</p>
      </div>


    </div>
  </li>



</ul>
```

You can see in the JS, I've added another var for `otras` and then used that to find the `divs` content you're looking for.

You'll notice that you now need to type more than one character (using your numbers as the base), because both tabs contain 1-4 `(1,2,3,4,10,11,12,13,14)`.

The fiddle if you want to see it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/rctzqw75/17/

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, man!!!. But, one thing though, how come I'm not able to search for the main accordion title anymore, and in the fiddle, they disappear for every two letters that I search. That's the only thing missing.

Comment: Actually, in the fiddle, they don't disappear if you type more than one character, but they do here. Any idea why?

Comment: I've tried changing it, but still does the same thing.

Comment: @J.L Yeah! You're right. I forgot I had changed the `&&` to `+` on my local testing. I updated the code above so it works. I know you accepted the other answer already, but to make this answer actually complete, I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking exclusively for `a`'s *text*, go for the entire `li`'s content:

```js
const EL = s => document.querySelectorAll(s),
  ALL = (s, cb) => [...typeof s === 'string' ? EL(s) : s].forEach(cb);

function myFilter() {
  const val = this.value.trim(), // Get input value trimmed
    reg = new RegExp(val, 'ig'), // Construct case-insensitive global RegExp
    fil = this.getAttribute('data-filter'), // Get data attribute selector target "#myUL"
    CH = EL(fil)[0].children; // Get immediate children of UL (LI elements)
  ALL(CH, el => el.style.display = !val.length || reg.test(el.textContent) ? 'block':'none');
}

function myAccordion() {
  const panel = this.nextElementSibling;
  this.classList.toggle('active');
  panel.style.maxHeight = panel.style.maxHeight ? '' : panel.scrollHeight + 'px';
}

ALL('.accor', el => el.addEventListener('click', myAccordion));
ALL('[data-filter]', el => el.addEventListener('input', myFilter));
```

```css
#myUL,*{margin:0}*{box-sizing:border-box}#myInput{width:100%;padding:12px 23px 11px 13px}#myUL{list-style-type:none;padding:0}#myUL li a{padding:10px 10px 10px 15px;text-decoration:none;color:#000;display:block;text-align:left}#myUL li a:hover:not(.header){background-color:#ccc}.accor{background-color:#eee;color:#444;padding:18px;width:100%;border:none;outline:0;font-size:20px}.accor:hover,.active{background-color:#ccc}.accor:after{content:'open';color:#777;font-weight:700;float:right;margin-right:5px}.active:after{content:"close"}.panel{max-height:0;overflow:hidden;transition:max-height .1s ease-out;text-align:left;font-size:12px}.title{font-size:20px}.otras{font-style:italic}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" data-filter="#myUL" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete=off>
<ul id="myUL">
  <li>
    <a class="accor">1House</a>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="otras">
        <p class=title>2Search by this too</p>
        <p>3This is a sentence</p>
      </div>
      <div class="otras">
        <p class=title>4Also this</p>
        <p>5Another sentence to search </p>
      </div>
      <div class="otras">
        <p class=title>6And this too</p>
        <p>7Example of sentence</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="accor">8Search here</a>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="otras">
        <p class=title> 9A different set of title </p>
        <p>10A different set of </p>
      </div>
      <div class="otras">
        <p class=title>11Also this</p>
        <p>12Another sentence to search </p>
      </div>
      <div class="otras">
        <p class=title>13And this too</p>
        <p>14Example of sentence</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Rocko this is greaaaaaat!!! Please, do you mind explaining why this works, and what I had did not?

Comment: @J.L you were matching only the `a` element's text. Above, instead, I'm targeting the entire `li`'s content.

Comment: @J.L `CH = EL(fil)[0].children;` are the LI elements, and than I handle `.display` visibility to those LIs inside `ALL(CH,`

Comment: Wow!!! Niiiice! Is this compatible with all browsers?             And hey, I appreciate this, thank you for taking your time!

Comment: @J.L No, the syntax is ES6 and is compatible with evergreen browsers only. `ParentNode.children` is also not compatible newer only.